# Using JMeter to test a socket

Tags: java, sockets, automated-tests, jmeter

I would like to use JMeter to test an application that communicates over sockets. It is done in java. In the server I have the typical

```
myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);
```

For every connection a thread reads and understands a line.
And in clients I have the typical

```
clientSocket = new Socket(hostCM, 1025);
out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("some bit string here");
```

I would like to use JMeter or any other load testing tool to send lots of requests at the same time and make my stress and load testing. But I dont know how to prepare a test. Is is possible to do this in JMeter at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JMeter's Java Request Sampler:  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request

Answer (score 0):

So this is good info I was able to get my jmx working by setting the re-use connection and Set No delay in the TCP Sampler.  More info [here](https://jmeterworld.wordpress.com/2009/02/19/tcp-sampler-jmeter/).